# React for loop issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, break

I beg your pardon, I tried to use "break" statement in for loop while writing React JS, but eventually the state hasn't been updated. Did I use this statement correctly or the syntax shall be modified?

```
for (let i = j; i < 42; i += 6) {
    /* if(i > 35 && !board[i]){
      board[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    }
    else if (board[i]) {
      while (board[i-6 * k]) {
        k++;
      }
      board[i-6 * k] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    } */
    if (i > 35 && !board[i]) {
        board[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    } else if (board[i]) {
        board[i - 6] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I cannot comment, you don't seem to be updating your state, that's why it doesn't get updated.
You should either use hooks setBoard for example or if you have a class component (which seems to be your case) use this.state={....} to update your state. If you share more code I might be able to give you a better answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much, although my problem hasn't been sorted I am very appreciated

Comment: If you could share more code I might be able to help you more. As I already mentioned you are "not updating" your state. And it is unclear to me what you are trying to do or how the component is constructed. I can give you a solution but it would be just guessing what you are doing

Comment: https://codepen.io/bunansia/pen/KKXXKje Thank you  I found that I declared array of the same name twice that's why it didn't show up, apologize for the confusion and thanks again for your kindness @C.O.D.E.R